# I want to randomise the component displayed on a page in React js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

i want to build a web page that display each time a todolist from those i have in file **Todos** and that with a random way . for example show the TodoTeen then TodoFive and for each user will be a different view. My code is on two parts , part one is **Todo.jsx** is the parent and **TodoOne, TodoTwo, TodoThree ...*** are the childs. At the fist I made the switch from one component to another using   **setTodoState("");** where the string giving to this useState will change the component.

Todo.jsx :

```
import TodoEight from "./Todos/TodoEight";
import TodoSeven from "./Todos/TodoSeven";
import TodoSix from "./Todos/TodoSix";
import TodoFive from "./Todos/TodoFive";
import TodoNine from "./Todos/TodoNine";
import TodoTen from "./Todos/TodoTen";
import { SurveyContext } from "../Helpers/Contexts.js";

import { generateStringPair, generateParagraphPair } from "../stringManager.js";
import TodoEleven from "./Todos/TodoEleven";
import TodoTwelve from "./Todos/TodoTwelve";
import TodoThirteen from "./Todos/TodoThirteen";


function Todos() {
  const type1 = "sidebyside";
  const type2 = "topofeachother";

  const {  userId } = useContext(SurveyContext);



  const [TodoState, setTodoState] = useState("1");

  // the usestate for progressbar
  const [currentTodoState, setcurrentTodoState] = useState(1);

  //Total Todos
  const totalTodos = 15;

  const state = {
    TodoState,
    setTodoState,
    currentTodoState,
    setcurrentTodoState,
    totalTodos,
  };

  //generate Todos text randomly

  const [text1_1, text2_1] = generateStringPair(5, "randomChange");
  const [text1_2, text2_2] = generateStringPair(15, "match");
  const [text1_3, text2_3] = generateStringPair(5, "hardChange");
  const [text1_4, text2_4] = generateStringPair(10, "match");
  const [text1_5, text2_5] = generateStringPair(15, "randomChange");
  const [text1_6, text2_6] = generateStringPair(15, "hardChange");

  const [text1_7, text2_7] = generateStringPair(5, "randomChange");
  const [text1_8, text2_8] = generateStringPair(15, "match");
  const [text1_9, text2_9] = generateStringPair(5, "hardChange");
  const [text1_10, text2_10] = generateStringPair(10, "match"); //// !!!!!
  const [text1_11, text2_11] = generateStringPair(15, "randomChange");
  const [text1_12, text2_12] = generateStringPair(15, "hardChange");

  const [text1_13, text2_13] = generateParagraphPair("simplerror");
  const [text1_14, text2_14] = generateParagraphPair("simplerror");
  const [text1_15, text2_15] = generateParagraphPair("harderror");

  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 1,
      text1: text1_1,
      text2: text2_1,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 2,
      text1: text1_2,
      text2: text2_2,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 3,
      text1: text1_3,
      text2: text2_3,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 4,
      text1: text1_4,
      text2: text2_4,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 5,
      text1: text1_5,
      text2: text2_5,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 6,
      text1: text1_6,
      text2: text2_6,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 7,
      text1: text1_7,
      text2: text2_7,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 8,
      text1: text1_8,
      text2: text2_8,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 9,
      text1: text1_9,
      text2: text2_9,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 10,
      text1: text1_10,
      text2: text2_10,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 11,
      text1: text1_11,
      text2: text2_11,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 12,
      text1: text1_12,
      text2: text2_12,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 13,
      text1: text1_13,
      text2: text2_13,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 14,
      text1: text1_14,
      text2: text2_14,
    },
    {
      userId: userId,
      TodoId: 15,
      text1: text1_15,
      text2: text2_15,
    },
  ]);


  

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={state}>
    
      {TodoState === "1" && (
        <TodoOne
          type={type2}
          text1={items[0].text1}
          text2={items[0].text2}
        />
      )}
      {TodoState === "2" && (
        <TodoTwo
          type={type1}
          text1={items[1].text1}
          text2={items[1].text2}
        />
      )}
      {TodoState === "3" && (
        <TodoThree
          type={type2}
          text1={items[2].text1}
          text2={items[2].text2}
        />
      )}
      {TodoState === "4" && (
        <TodoFour
          type={type2}
          text1={items[3].text1}
          text2={items[3].text2}
        />
      )}

      {/* top of each other */}
      {TodoState === "5" && (
        <TodoFive
          type={type2}
          text1={items[4].text1}
          text2={items[4].text2}
        />
      )}
      {TodoState === "6" && (
        <TodoSix
          type={type1}
          text1={items[5].text1}
          text2={items[5].text2}
        />
      )}
      {TodoState === "7" && (
        <TodoSeven text1={items[6].text1} text2={items[6].text2} />
      )}
      {TodoState === "8" && (
        <TodoEight text1={items[7].text1} text2={items[7].text2} />
      )}
      {/* /Red_blue */}

      {TodoState === "9" && (
        <TodoNine text1={items[8].text1} text2={items[8].text2} />
      )}

      {TodoState === "10" && (
        <TodoTen text1={items[9].text1} text2={items[9].text2} />
      )}
      {TodoState === "11" && (
        <TodoEleven text1={items[10].text1} text2={items[10].text2} />
      )}

     
      {TodoState === "12" && (
        <TodoTwelve text1={items[11].text1} text2={items[11].text2} />
      )}

      {TodoState === "13" && (
        <TodoThirteen
          type={type1}
          text1={items[12].text1}
          text2={items[12].text2}
        />
      )}
      )}
```

and an example of childs is :

```
import { TodoContext } from "../../Helpers/TodosContext";
import ProgressBar from "../ProgressBar";

import "./Todos.css";

const TodoOne = (props) => {
  const {
    TodoState,
    setTodoState,
    currentTodoState,
    setcurrentTodoState,
    totalTodos,
  } = useContext(TodoContext);



  return (
    <section className="section_Todos">
      <ProgressBar
        currentTodoIndex={currentTodoState}
        totalTodosCount={totalTodos}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <main className="optional_Todos">
      
        <h1>props.text1</h1>
        <h1>props.text2</h1>
      </main>
      <div className="text-center button-container">
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary d-inline-flex flex-row align-items-center"
          onClick={() => {
            setTodoState("2");
            setcurrentTodoState(currentTodoState + 1);
          }}
        >
          Next
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default TodoOne;
```

Comment: What is the question? What is not working in your code? If you are asking of a different way of selecting the random list, I will make a generic list component, and passing a randomly selected content from the parent (this way you do not need to have one component per list).

Comment: this code here is my first code without randomizing. in this code i puted  **const [TodoState, setTodoState] = useState("1");** at the first to display TodoOne, and when i change the state of the value **TodoState** in the function onclick , it change the Todo to the corresponding number. but now i want to randomize that without i change the state manually.

Comment: Then you can set the value of TodoState to Math.floor(Math.random() * {number_of_todos}), where {number_of_todos} is the number of todos lists you have. Since your conditional statements use strings, remember to convert the result to string:

const [TodoState, setTodoState] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13 + 1) + "");